# Multiple Methods NSNotificationCenter iPhone

Tags: iphone, methods, selector, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

I have many methods that need the previous one to complete before firing the next one. I'm thinking I should NSNotificationCenter rather than performSelector afterDelay and just hope the method is done by that time.

Can someone map out how and where to add the notification to Method1, Method2 and Method3 where 1 needs to complete (not just fire) before 2 before 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general do not use notifications as method calls. They should be used to indicate that something did or will occur.

From Apple's "Coding Guidelines for Cocoa":

Notifications are identified by global NSString objects whose names are composed in this way:
          [Name of associated class] + [Did | Will] + [UniquePartOfName] + Notification
For example:

```
NSApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification  
NSWindowDidMiniaturizeNotification  
NSTextViewDidChangeSelectionNotification  
NSColorPanelColorDidChangeNotification
```

Comment: So how would I set the notification to run when the end of the method did occur?

Comment: If I set the Notification to Post when the returned object from the method completion is created, I can use Notification Center. Thanks!